# How do I set the image path I uploaded in Spring?

Tags: spring, file, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm currently implements File Upload.

When you write, you will go to the view page with the index value of the corresponding post.

When I moved to the view page, I added a list of files that I added to the model.

BoardController.java

```
@RequestMapping("viewPage.do")
public String viewPage(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, 
        @RequestParam(value="board_idx", defaultValue="0") int board_idx) throws IOException,IllegalStateException
{
    checkLogin(request, response, session);
    // select File List
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> selectFile = bService.selectAllBoardFile(board_idx);
    System.out.println("selectFile >> " + selectFile);

    model.addAttribute("boardFile", selectFile);
    return "viewPage";
}
```

The result values ​​are as follows.

```
selectFile >> [{boardFile_filePath=C:/rachel/c22b20e098.png, boardFile_serverPath=/boardFile/c22b20e098.png, board_idx=18, boardFile_oName=img_6.png, boardFile_idx=4}]
```

The values ​​in the model have been taken from jsp to el.

viewPage.jsp

```
        <c:forEach items="${boardFile}" var="img" varStatus="index">
        <div class="imageListArea" name="imageListArea">
            <div class="imageArea_1">
                <img alt="" src="${img.boardFile_filePath}" class="registeredIMG" id="ri1_img_1">
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
```

However, it can not display the image well and causes the following error.
[image]

Why is this happening?

Is there an error because the settings are wrong?

How to solve that..??

I need your help. please help me.

Comment: try using boardFile_serverPath instead of boardFile_filePath in the jsp

Comment: I got the settings to get the file from the server, but I got an error.

Comment: If you original problem is resolved then it may be better to create a new question.

Comment: I solved that :)